# Defining a new function to evaluate a previously defined function at specified parameter set, using fewer inputs?

Tags: functions, function-construction

I have a function in three variables:

```
f[var1_,var2_,var3_]:=expression[var1,var2,var3];
```

I want to reduce this to `g[var3]` and have it output `f[10,20,var3]`.

Hopefully you get the idea.  I want to create a new function g by evaluating f at two of its three inputs, how do I do this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `f[10,20,var3]`, that is, drop the blank (_) on the RHS.

Answer (score 2):

B.! @Carl Woll's answer is a great one, it would look like this:

```
f[var1_,var2_,var3_]:=expression[var1,var2,var3];
g[altvar3_]:=f[10,20,altvar3];
```

Notice that you don't have to stick to the same naming convention for the expressions which you create another function for. Though, I may suggest a method that looks a bit fancier, and uses pure functions, which I prefer to use in code to save space, though with taking a hit on readability if the user is unfamiliar. Find it below:

```
g=Evaluate[f[10,20,#]]&;
```

Off hand, I don't know if it runs any faster or does much more than make you use pure functions, but hey! It's a different answer :D

Also notice that you don't *necessarily* need to use a `:= SetDelayed` method of defining the function, and maybe this will help you come up with some neat tricks where you define the initial function one way, use this redefinition/reduction method to define `g` and then `ClearAll` and `Remove` the initial function definition, as the `= Set` would evaluate the initial function at that very moment, but actually you have to wrap it in an `Evaluate` if you are to do what I just suggested, but my note about the use of `:=` remains true to form, as that would evaluate f upon execution of your redefined/alternative function `g`.

```
g:=f[10,20,#];
g=f[10,20,#];
g:=Evaluate[f[10,20,#]]&;
```

Will all accomplish what you desire, and all of these would carry the same required input of `g[altv3]` to achieve evaluation!

Hope this helps!